# как сделать горизонтальное фиксированное меню из вертикального?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3

Такая проблема, есть у меня вертикальное меню из 3 пунктов, есть логотип и некоторые контакты. Все это на главном экране.
Как всунуть лого, контакты и меню в горизонтальное фиксированное меню при прокрутке. Я только начинаю разбираться с этой проблемой, но пока не очень получается.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > $('header').height() + 10)
    $('main-menu').addClass('fixed');
  else
    $('main-menu').removeClass('fixed');
});
```

```css
.logo {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 40%;
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: 120px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mail_header {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 2%;
  font-family: GothamProRegular;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #e7e7e7;
}

.main-menu {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: 120px;
}

.main-menu li {
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-left: -35px;
  border-radius: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: center;
  border: 2px solid white;
  height: 40px;
  width: 220px;
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.fixed {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  background: #000;
}

.main-menu a {
  padding: 5px 0 0 0;
  font-family: GothamProRegular;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none !important;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.main-menu a:hover {
  color: #141414;
}

.main-menu li:hover {
  margin-left: -15px;
  background-color: #fff;
  transition: .2s ease;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="main-menu">
  <li><a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll ('#offers')">Услуги</a></li>
  <li><a href="#portfolio">Портфолио</a></li>
  <li><a href="javascript://0" onclick="slowScroll ('#contacts')">Контакты</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="container clearfix">
  <div class="mail_header">info@mysite.com<br> +0000000000<br> +0000000000</div>
  <a href="index.php"><img src="img/logotype.png" alt="logo" class="logo"></a>
```

Изначально экран выглядит так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При скроле должен выглядеть так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почему бы вам не попробовать продублировать текущую вертикальную версию меню в горизонтальную, и скрывать/отображать их JS в зависимости от положения скролла?

Comment: @RifmaMan Я думал об этом, но с моими знаниями в js пока не сильно понимаю как это осуществить. Вы можете помочь с этим?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский , пока моя задача заключена немного в другом)

Comment: @МаксимЛенский , Вы можете мне помочь с этим? Буду очень благодарен

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, Он лишний, я кинул то на чем застрял. Теперь я понял, что делал плохо.

Comment: @МаксимЛенский , но это адаптивное меню. 
мне нужно чтобы вертикальное меню при скролинге переходило в горизонтальное фиксированное

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, я внес правки, посмотрите вверху, пожалуйста

Comment: @ЮрийГалай  вот здесь почитайте что да как : https://webref.ru

Comment: @RifmaMan Простите, но вы можете хоть примерно сказать на что ориентироваться?

Comment: @ЮрийГалай  сделал - так надо ? Прости не понял с первого раза ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прошу прощения,не понял сразу что требуется

```js
var w = $(document);
var m = $("ul");
var h = $("header");
var b = $("html,body");


w.scroll(function() {
  var sc = w.scrollTop();
  if (sc >= 100) {
    m.addClass("menu");
    h.addClass('fixed');
    b.css({
      "padding-top": "200px"
    })
  } else {
    m.removeClass("menu");
    h.removeClass('fixed');
    b.css({
      "padding-top": "0"
    })
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  min-height: 3000px;
}

header {
  height: 250px;
  background: lightblue;
}

ul.menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 0;
  flex-direction: row;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

ul li {
  margin-left: 20px;
}

ul {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
  <li><a href="">item1</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item2</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item3</a></li>
  <li><a href="">item4</a></li>
</ul>
```

demo : https://codepen.io/topicstarter/full/GdvdGj

Comment: Ничего страшного. Спасибо, я уже сам разобрался.

Answer (score 0):

Вам просто нужно сверстать еще одно меню (просто имеется в виду в логике реализации а не в верстке). 1-е меню будет в одном блоке к примеру `<div class="main-menu">` а горизонтальное во 2-ом `<div class="sub-menu">` и при скролле js будет отображать либо основное, либо горизонтальное меню.

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(document).scrollTop() > ($('.main-menu').height() + 10)) {        
        $('.main-menu').hide(); // скрыть основное меню и показать горизонтальное
        $('.sub-menu').show();
    } else {
        $('.main-menu').show(); // или наоборот
        $('.sub-menu').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, попробую сделать.

Comment: не `scroll` а `resize` наверно ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский событие нужно повесить на скролл вниз, причем тут ресайз? )

Comment: он хотел что бы при скролле сделать меню горизонтальное ?

Comment: @МаксимЛенский именно при прокрутке (см. описание вопроса)

Comment: я в первый раз не понял - наехал на него : каюсь

Comment: тогда не надо дублировать или создавать другое меню